# RxJava subscribe return null object

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

What's wrong woth my code?

Below my json object from the server

```
{"Items": [
{
  "DistrictID": 1,
  "DistrictName": "sample string 2",
  "DistrictCode": "sample string 3",
  "RegionID": 4
},
{
  "DistrictID": 1,
  "DistrictName": "sample string 2",
  "DistrictCode": "sample string 3",
  "RegionID": 4
} ]}
```

my Api request

```
@GET("api/Taxes/GetDistricts")
fun getDistricts(): Observable<DistrictItems>
```

my District items model

```
 data class DistrictItems(
     var items: List<TaxDistrictModel>?
```

)

my TaxDistrictModel

```
data class TaxDistrictModel(

    var DistrictID: Int?,

    var DistrictName: String?,

    var DistrictCode: String?,

    var RegionID: Int?
)
```

function where I call request

```
fun getRegions(): DistrictItems? {
     showLoading()
     api.getDistricts()
               .subscribeOnMain(
                       onNext = {
                           hideLoading()
                           Log.d("qwerty", "$$$$$$$$ ${it.items?.size}")
                           districtModelTypeTitles = it
                       },
                       onError = { showAlert(it) }
               )
               .disposedBy(compositeDisposable)
    return districtModelTypeTitles
}
```

In Log it's showing null size of a list.

```
D/qwerty: $$$$$$$$ null
```

I'm really stuck on this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the JSON field names are case sensitive --- details depending on your JSON parsing library. Your data has `Items` while your model class has `items`. Hence the list comes out as null.